# How to change InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT Lock Modes on Debian?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mysql-python

I create a table with **auto_increment**, and insert into it a lot of data.

My database skip number while I am using auto-increment, i found that i have to change the `auto_incremet_lock_mode = 0`, but i didn't find, where i have to do this change on Debian system?

I tried to find the **my.cnf** file in **/etc/mysql/** but it contains only 2 rows, so i don't know how i can change it. I read the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization) site too but there isn't any information about it.

Comment: I posted this link too..

Answer (score 2):

It was hard, but i found the answer!

- 1. edit the /etc/my.cnf file with
     `[mysqld] 
     innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0`
     //You have to use autoinc_lock_mode inside this [mysqld] part!
- 2. restart/reload configs with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: I can in 57 minutes!